# How to acess system timestamp in WIX msi?

Tags: wix, timestamp, windows-installer

I am trying to create an msi installer. Installer should move an existing file to another location.And  in the new location 
filename = timestamp + filename 
I am able to move the file ..but not able to access the system timestamp.

Is there any way to do this.
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Windows Installer has [predefined Time property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372079(v=vs.85).aspx), which is most likely what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Date] and [Time] variables for your timestamp.

Wix supports those.